# Creating json object in JSP

Tags: arrays, json, jsp, loops, iteration

I am creating a sample web application with front end using Angular JS and Material design. I am a front end guy and have no much knowledge of backed. I wanted to create a JSP page which will create json and serve as a service to my application. i have written the code like as follows

```
  <%@page contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"%>
  <%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
  <%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>

  <%

      JSONObject userAppJsonObj = new JSONObject();

         userAppJsonObj.put("icon","fa fa-2x fa-home");
         userAppJsonObj.put("title","Home");     
         userAppJsonObj.put("authorized",true);


      out.print(userAppJsonObj);
      out.flush();
  %>
```

Above is working fine. i am finding some difficulty in iteration when i want the output josn as follows

```
   [
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-home", title: "Home", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-line-chart", title: "About", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-code", title: "Service", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-bar-chart", title: "Blog", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-flask", title: "Contact", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-pie-chart", title: "Studio", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-object-group", title: "Map", authorized: true },
            { icon: "fa fa-2x fa-database", title: "Offers", authorized: true },
  ]
```

Thanks in advance.